# convert string from MM/DD/YYYY to YYYYMMDD

Tags: pervasive, pervasive-sql

My date column is stored as a CHAR and in YYYYMMDD format. The string I have to search from this column is in MM/DD/YYYY format. How could I change it to YYYYMMDD. Also if my parametr is passed NULL to the query I do not include the DOB search in the WHERE clause

```
select * 
from ona 
  left join mnv on ona.xyz = mnv.xyz 
where (coalesce(to_date(mnv.DOB,'YYYYMMDD'),to_date('1901-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')) OR '{BirthDate}' IS NULL)
```

Comment: is not possible to convert to date at all? Like reverse and then changing positioning

Answer (score 3):

It is not suggested to store dates as string, mainly due to this particular reason. So try to change your column datatype if possible to avoid this in future.

For now, you can compare it, by converting both of the strings to date, with `to_date` function.

```
select something from some_table where
to_date(date_Column,'YYYYMMDD')=to_date(search_value,'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

As you asked in comments, it is possible to do it by manupulating the strings also however I think comparing by dates would be faster and less prone to inaccuracy.

Update after seeing your query.

You are not converting `BirthDate` to date and also there is no `=` to compare in your query. Assuming that BirthDate is a string with `MM/DD/YYYY` format, use something like below.

```
select * from ona left join mnv on ona.xyz = mnv.xyz 
where
to_date(mnv.DOB,'YYYYMMDD') = to_date(BirthDate,'MM/DD/YYYY')
and mnv.DOB is not null 
and BirthDate is not null.
```

Comment: OR '{BirthDate}' IS NULL in my where is clause is to exclude searching on the date in the query where the parameter is NULL

Comment: That's better actually.

Comment: (mnv.DOB = coalesce(to_date(date_Column,'YYYYMMDD'),to_date('1901-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')) OR '{BirthDate}' IS NULL). to_date is throwing an error, scalar function not recognized.

Comment: you are comparing the date to `mnb.DOB`. Is it a date or char? If char that use same `to_date` conversion for it also while comparing.

Comment: mnv.DOB is a char. pervasive is not recognizing to_date

Comment: But you are not converting `mnv.DOB` to date while comparing. Give your minimal query to verify. Edit it in the question.

Comment: check the updated answer and run the exact query. If not working give the exact error message in the question. Hope someone sees it, else I will check in morning as it is getting very late here. Cheers.

Comment: @user7822440: you tagged your question with `postgresql`. **pervasive** is a completely different DBMS. What exactly are you using?

Comment: Sorry guys, I am using pervasive SQL.